# Predicate to check if a set is a subpart of another set checks correctly but generates only void set

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to Prolog, and I'm trying to implement a function to generate all subparts of a given set(it seems to be a classical exercise).

I coded this:

```
%evaluate if the list PH|PT is part of the list EH|ET
partof([],[_|_]).
partof([PH|PT],[EH|ET]):-
    \+(member(PH,PT)),%no duplicated element to limit results
    member(PH,[EH|ET]),%check if head element is in E
    partof(PT,[EH|ET]).%check the rest of the list
```

When fed with "concrete" variables, my predicate indicate correctly if the first list is a subpart of the second one :

```
?- partof([b,c],[a,b,c]).
true .

?- partof([a,c],[a,b,c]).
true .

?- partof([a,a,c],[a,b,c]).
false.

?- partof([a,u,c],[a,b,c]).
false.
```

My problem is, when fed with unlinked variable, it only returns the void list and not all the subparts:

```
%Expecting [a],[a,b],[a,b,c],[b],[b,c]... etc
9 ?- partof(P,[a,b,c]). 
P = [] ;
false.
```

I would much appreciate not only a correction but also an explanation about how prolog predicates work when fed with unlink variables, as I was assuming than the very nature of Prolog implied that a "checker" is equivalent to a "generator"

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your `partof/2` rule succeeds to give the answer `P = []`, it's the second part that's failing for you. Let's take a look at why:

```
partof([PH|PT],[EH|ET]):-
    \+(member(PH,PT)),%no duplicated element to limit results
    member(PH,[EH|ET]),%check if head element is in E
    partof(PT,[EH|ET]).%check the rest of the list
```

If you trace it you'll see that when you get to the line `\+(member(PH, PT)`, if `[PH|PT]` was a variable, then `PT` is still a variable. Therefore `member(PH, PT)` succeeds to unify `PT = [PH|_]`. The next check Prolog does is the `\+`, and seen as `member(PH, PT)` is true, `\+ true` resolves to false and fails.

This is the difference between a logical "not" and Prolog's `\+`. By necessity `\+` carries some procedural meaning, more akin to "if you can't prove this goal right now, then fail. It's the procedural meaning of Prolog that can trip you up when going from checker to generator.

Knowing you need to have this ground before testing suggests you can re-order the goals to get (*almost*) the desired result:

```
partof([],[_|_]).
partof([PH|PT],[EH|ET]):-
    partof(PT,[EH|ET]),
    member(PH,[EH|ET]),%check if head element is in E
    \+ (member(PH,PT)).%no duplicated element to limit results
```

This will find the correct answers now, but it will also fail to terminate because you have no constraints on the generated length of the subset list. You can gain this by placing the generation (which will be guards if arguments are ground) into one predicate that then uses another to make the generated list into a suitable set:

```
partof(Sub, Set) :-
    length(Set, L),  % measure length if Set is a list
    length(Sub, SL),  % generate list of vars of increasing length if Sub is a var
    ( SL > L, !, fail  % We've generated a Sub longer than Set, quit the search
    ; SL =< L,  % We've got an appropriate length Sub
    partof_(Set, Sub)  % Hand off to helper predicate
    ).

% This is practically the same as the re-ordering of yours
% But with the generative aspect removed. It'll unify any variables
% in the arguments subject to the constraints placed on them.
partof_(Set, []).
partof_(Set, [H|T]) :-
    partof_(Set, T),
    member(H, Set), 
    \+ member(H, T).
```

**Note**, this is still not a complete solution, but it's probably enough to get on with for now.

It has some bad "quirks", the `!` means no results are returned for:

```
?- partof([a, b], Y).
false.
```

Furthermore, there is no checking to see if `Set` actually is a set, although it terminates if given an inappropriate input such as:

```
?- partof(Sub, [a, b, c, a]).
```

You'll get strange results if you query:

```
?- partof([a, c], [a, B, c]).
B = a ;
true ;
B = c.
```

To circumvent these you only want to `!` cut when `Sub` is not ground, if it is ground and `SL > L` then just fail without the cut to infinitely generate sets that sub can be a subset of. Then end `partof/2` with guards that check both `Set` and `Sub` are actually sets before allowing the predicate to succeed.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i really did not understand the \+ meaning, despite being warned by every single prolog documentation